# matplotlib legend based only on line style but not color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting values of two metrics for two different algorithms in different style and colors in a single plot.
I use different styles for different algorithms and different colors for different metrics.
I want the legend to be based only on line style only.

My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
x = np.arange(0,4)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
d_gc = np.array([1.718,1.742,1.778,1.0])
q_gc = np.array([1.709,1.737,1.761,0.98])


p1 = ax1.plot(x,d_gc,'bs--',label='A1')
p2 = ax1.plot(x,q_gc,'bs:',label='A2')
ax1.set_ylabel('GC',color='b',size=13)
ax1.set_ylim([0.9,2])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
d_df = np.array([1.00, 1.958, 1.982, 1.995])
q_df = np.array([0.97, 1.930, 1.973, 1.994])

ax2.plot(x,d_df,'cv--')
ax2.plot(x,q_df,'cv:')
ax2.set_ylabel('DF',color='c',size=13)
ax2.set_ylim([0.9,2])

ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MaxNLocator(20))
ax1.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.25)
ax1.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)

p = p1 + p2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in p]
lgd = ax1.legend(p, labs, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.22),loc=0, ncol = 2, fontsize='11',shadow=True,fancybox=True)
fig.savefig('plot.pdf',format='pdf',transparent=True, bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

In the above legend comes with different colors.  But I have the metrics GC and DF in different colors and algorithms 'A1' and 'A2' in different styles.  I want the legend to be in black color with different line styles.  Is it possible to do that using `legend` function ?

Comment: Hi I would like to help, however I am not sure I understand the point. Should the legend (besides being of black color) also include the marker?

Comment: @BjörnB.  Yes, legend should be exactly like how it appears in normal case when you run the code, except that I need it to have same color, that is black.  Line style and markers should be same as original, except color.

Comment: Can the markers in the legend still be colored or do you want them to be also black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you only want the lines in the legend to be black this is easily done with a simple list comprehension and a legendHandle, like this (it has to be inserted after you created the legend, in the line `lgd = ...`

```
leg = ax1.get_legend()
[lgd.set_color('black') for lgd in leg.legendHandles]
```

Otherwise you can create two custom lines with the `mlines` and set the `markersize = 0`then you only have the linestyle

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

labs = [l.get_label() for l in p]
black_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', marker='s',linestyle="--",
                          markersize=0, label=labs[0])
black_line2 = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', marker='s',linestyle=":",
                          markersize=0, label=labs[1])

lgd = ax1.legend(p, labs, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.22), loc=0, ncol=2,
                 fontsize='11', shadow=True, fancybox=True,numpoints=2,
                 handles=[black_line,black_line2])
```

In the image below I changed the position of the legend for convience purposes to `loc = 2`

[image: Exemplary black only linestyle legend]

Comment: `p` is not defined in the code.